# Unable to play sound even after installing playsound in python

Tags: python, mp3, python-playsound

Downloaded the sound from https://sounds-mp3.com/, and the syntax of the playsound was from the official site of it. Still there is no sound played and giving me the below mentioned output of execution.

```py
from playsound import playsound

playsound('C:\\Users\\HP\\Downloads\\0003537.mp3')
```

output:

> python -u "c:\Users\HP\Desktop\python files\hello.py"

Comment: Where did you find which code? What do you want to do

Comment: DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text. For more information please see the Meta FAQ entry [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt it is a problem with the code, it looks fine.

It might be to do with your speakers or the audio file. Try out a wav and see if that works. Check your path too. I have had problems in the past with files downloaded from the web so maybe record something on Audacity and see if that plays. Try playing the audio file with the default software for your os, does it work?